# Где можно скачать исходники андроид?

Tags: android

Где можно скачать исходный код любой версии операционной системы?

Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По запросу в поисковик "android open source project" находятся следующие ссылки:

- https://source.android.com/
- https://github.com/aosp-mirror

Пожалуй, это то, что нужно. На странице полно документации о том, как все настроить и начать разрабатывать.